# can an an ORM column trigger a session flush in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

## Question

Can a property access trigger a session flush in SQLAlchemy? My expectation would be for, e.g., queries attached to an object via column_property() or @hybrid_property to cause a session autoflush, in the same way that queries made through session.Query() do. That does not seem to be the case.

In the simple example below, an Account contains an Entry collection. It also provides a "balance" property, constructed with column_property(), that exposes a select-sum query. New entries only appear in an account's balance if session.flush() is called explicitly.

This behavior seems suboptimal: users of the Account class need to sprinkle flush() calls throughout their code based on knowing the internals of the balance implementation. If the implementation changes---e.g., if "balance" was previously a Python @property---bugs can be introduced even though the Account interface is essentially identical. Is there an alternative?

## Complete Example

```python
import sys
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.sql
import sqlalchemy.orm
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative

Base = sa.ext.declarative.declarative_base()

class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = "entries"

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = sa.Column(sa.Numeric, primary_key=True)
    account_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("accounts.id"))
    account = sa.orm.relationship("Account", backref="entries")

class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = "accounts"

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    balance = sa.orm.column_property(
        sa.sql.select([sa.sql.func.sum(Entry.value)])
            .where(Entry.account_id == id)
        )

def example(database_url):
    # connect to the database and prepare the schema
    engine = sa.create_engine(database_url)
    session = sa.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

    Base.metadata.create_all(bind = engine)

    # add an entry to an account
    account = Account()

    account.entries.append(Entry(value = 42))

    session.add(account)

    # and look for that entry in the balance
    print "account.balance:", account.balance

    assert account.balance == 42

if __name__ == "__main__":
    example(sys.argv[1])
```

## Observed Output

```sh
$ python sa_column_property_example.py postgres:///za_test
account.balance: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sa_column_property_example.py", line 46, in <module>
    example(sys.argv[1])
  File "sa_column_property_example.py", line 43, in example
    assert account.balance == 42
AssertionError
```

## Preferred Output

I'd like to see "account.balance: 42", without adding an explicit call to session.flush().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a column_property is only evaluated at query time, that is when you say query(Account), as well as when the attribute is expired, that is if you said session.expire("account", ['balance']).

To have an attribute invoke a query every time, we use a @property (some small mods here for the script to work with sqlite):

```
import sys
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.sql
import sqlalchemy.orm
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative

Base = sa.ext.declarative.declarative_base()

class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = "entries"

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = sa.Column(sa.Numeric)
    account_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("accounts.id"))
    account = sa.orm.relationship("Account", backref="entries")

class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = "accounts"

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)

    @property
    def balance(self):
        return sqlalchemy.orm.object_session(self).query(
                    sa.sql.func.sum(Entry.value)
                ).filter(Entry.account_id == self.id).scalar()

def example(database_url):
    # connect to the database and prepare the schema
    engine = sa.create_engine(database_url, echo=True)
    session = sa.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

    Base.metadata.create_all(bind = engine)

    # add an entry to an account
    account = Account()

    account.entries.append(Entry(value = 42))

    session.add(account)

    # and look for that entry in the balance
    print "account.balance:", account.balance

    assert account.balance == 42

if __name__ == "__main__":
    example("sqlite://")
```

Note that "flushing" itself is generally not something we have to worry about; the autoflush feature will ensure flush is called each time query() goes to the database to get results, so it's really ensuring that a query occurs which is what we're going for.

Another approach to this issue is to use hybrids.  I'd recommend reading the overview of all three methods at [SQL Expressions as Mapped Attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes) which lists out the tradeoffs to each approach.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I think I'm just tilting at SQLAlchemy design decisions here: in hindsight, the behavior I was hoping for was something like "column_property should execute a query if, and only if, the session is dirty, and use the cached value otherwise" (while also playing nicely with query expressions). Sounds like I'll have to build that behavior using hybrid_property, if I truly want it. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you could actually get that, by listening for attribute change events and expiring the column_property in response to it.   I think it's apparent that if all column properties expired every time any attribute anywhere went dirty, that would be excessive.   the column_prop can't decide by itself which in-memory attributes it may be dependent on (if any).